# Why can I not authenticate with peripheral device?

Tags: c++, .net, networking, tcp, network-protocols

**Language version:** Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x85) – 12.0.30501

**Platform version:** 4.0

**Operating system:** Microsoft Windows 8.1 6.3.9600 Build 9600

**Any other relevant software:**

1. Visual Studio 2013 Community with update 4
2. Halo Configuration Control Panel
3. Halo Hub

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to communicate with a peripheral device that is using the OSDP protocol.

**What is actually happening**

I get the following from the output panel in visual studio.

1. Received valid packet of 326 bytes
2. Received authentication response from OSDP Hub
3. Session Key > E856417D8B0364313A4B8F0D89524273F0F70AB1DFF8E950FE96905FECAC9F2F
4. Received packet after 3 ms
5. Received valid packet of 4 bytes
6. Received authentication denial from OSDP Hub
7. Received packet after 0 ms
8. Performing a search on 0 devices

**Rough Copy**

```
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Work\velox\admins-velox-project\proprietary\rtos\apps\chibios\utilities\osdp_client\Debug_msvc\osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 

'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 

'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.18006_none_a9ec6aab013aafee\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Internet Helper Anti-phishing\internetHelper_antiphishing.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IconCodecService.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.18696_none_dae05f525bc50fb1\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Password = 1234
Private key = 03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067
Added 0 items
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
..\..\src\common\strvararg.cpp(658): assert "n <= parser.nargs" failed in `anonymous-namespace'::DoGetArgumentType(): more arguments than format string specifiers? [in thread cb4]
First-chance exception at 0x76165608 (KernelBase.dll) in osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe: 0x00001976.
'osdp_client_mswud_vc11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: .
DBGHELP: .\wkernelbase.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\wkernelbase.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\wkernelbase.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: wkernelbase.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: KERNELBASE - export symbols
DBGHELP: .\osdp_client_mswud_vc11.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\exe\osdp_client_mswud_vc11.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\exe\osdp_client_mswud_vc11.pdb - file not found
Received valid packet of 326 bytes
Received authentication response from OSDP Hub
Session Key > 63B2D0C583090EFD994B5AFE12A417A07F406CEE1F64DCB1613703B45428E32E
Received packet after 3 ms
Received valid packet of 4 bytes
Received authentication denial from OSDP Hub
Received packet after 2 ms
DBGHELP: osdp_client_mswud_vc11 - private symbols & lines 
        C:\Work\velox\admins-velox-project\proprietary\rtos\apps\chibios\utilities\osdp_client\Debug_msvc\osdp_client_mswud_vc11.pdb
DBGHELP: .\msvcr120d.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\msvcr120d.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\msvcr120d.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: msvcr120d.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: MSVCR120D - export symbols
DBGHELP: .\wntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\wntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\wntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: wntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll - export symbols
DBGHELP: .\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\DLL\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\DLL\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: KERNEL32 - export symbols
```

Here is the actual code;

```
case OSDP_HUB:
{
    bool ipv4;
    uint8_t ip_addr[16];

    osdp_hub_messages* hub = (osdp_hub_messages*)m_packets.get_data( OSDP_HUB );

    // goes from here to decode method ondown
    hub->decode( (uint8_t*)buffer, m_packets.get_header()->m_data.length );

    if ( hub->get_msg_type() == OSDP_HUB_TCP_IND )
    {
        hub->get_ip_addr( &ipv4, ip_addr );

        if ( hub->get_enable() )
        {
                        // Device has connected...
            wxLogDebug( wxT("Device connected on IP address %d.%d.%d.%d : %u"),
                ip_addr[0], ip_addr[1], ip_addr[2], ip_addr[3], hub->get_tcp_port() );

            m_tcp_device_connected = true;

                        // Assign an address
                        /// @todo Create an address generation function
            std::vector<uint8_t> ip_addr_vec;
            ip_addr_vec.resize( ipv4? 4 : 16 );
            memcpy( &ip_addr_vec[0], ip_addr, ipv4? 4 : 16 );
            m_tcp_map[0] = ip_addr_vec;

            MyCustomEvent customEvent( MyCustomCommandEvent, ID_EVENT_TCP_ADD );
            customEvent.SetText( _T( "SocketThread::Entry() ID_EVENT_TCP_ADD" ) );
            wxPostEvent( m_parent, customEvent );
        }
        else
        {
                        // Device has disconnected...
            wxLogDebug( wxT("Device disconnected on IP address %d.%d.%d.%d"),
                ip_addr[0], ip_addr[1], ip_addr[2], ip_addr[3] );

                        // Change the UI to display the nearest device on the list
            MyCustomEvent customEvent( MyCustomCommandEvent, ID_EVENT_TCP_REMOVE );
            customEvent.SetText( _T( "SocketThread::Entry() ID_EVENT_TCP_REMOVE" ) );
            wxPostEvent( m_parent, customEvent );
        }
    }
    else if ( hub->get_msg_type() == OSDP_HUB_AUTH_1 )
    {
        wxLogDebug( wxT("Received authentication response from OSDP Hub") );

        m_auth1_received = true;

        std::string salt = hub->get_salt();
        std::string key = hub->get_publickey();
        m_srp_auth->gen_client_session_key( salt, key );
        wxLogDebug( wxT("Session Key > %s"), m_srp_auth->get_session_key() );
        m_srp_auth->gen_client_cryptogram();
    }
    else if ( hub->get_msg_type() == OSDP_HUB_AUTH_3 ) // skips here
    {
        wxLogDebug( wxT("Received authentication accept from OSDP Hub") );

        m_auth3_received = true;
    }
    else if ( hub->get_msg_type() == OSDP_HUB_AUTH_4 ) // enters in here
    {
        wxLogDebug( wxT("Received authentication denial from OSDP Hub") );

        m_auth4_received = true;
    }
    else if ( hub->get_msg_type() == OSDP_HUB_PONG )
    {
        wxLogDebug( wxT("Received PONG from OSDP Hub") );

        m_pong_received = true;

        int32_t length;
        hub->encode( (uint8_t*)msg, &length );
        m_clientSocket->Write( (char*)msg, length );
    }
} break;


//comes in here
int32_t osdp_hub_messages::decode( uint8_t* buffer, int32_t len )
{
    return osdp_hub_messages_decode( &m_osdp_hub_messages, buffer, len );

} // decode()


// then comes in here
int32_t osdp_hub_messages_decode( osdp_hub_messages_t* data, uint8_t* buffer, int32_t len )
{
    //goes from OSDP_HUB_AUTH_2 t0 OSDP_HUB_AUTH_4
    //never hits OSDP_HUB_START or OSDP_HUB_TCP_IND
    data->hub_msg = (osdp_hub_e)buffer[0];


    switch ( data->hub_msg )
    {
        case OSDP_HUB_START: return decode_start( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_TCP_IND: return decode_tcp_ind( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_AUTH_0: return decode_auth_0( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_AUTH_1: return decode_auth_1( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_AUTH_2: return decode_auth_2( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_AUTH_3: return decode_auth_2( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_AUTH_4: return decode_auth_4( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_PING: return decode_ping( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_PONG: return decode_pong( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_GET_AUTH_1: return decode_get_auth_1( data, buffer+1, len ); break;
        case OSDP_HUB_GET_AUTH_3: return decode_get_auth_3( data, buffer+1, len ); break;

        default:
        {
            return 0;
        } break;
    }

} // osdp_hub_messages_decode()

//additional code


/// @file osdp_halo_alarm_base.h
/// @brief A C implementation of the proprietary Halo alarm packet.
///
/// @author neil

#pragma once

#include "osdp_header.h"


#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/// The ID used to define a HALO HUB packet
#define OSDP_HUB    0x00

typedef enum
{
    OSDP_HUB_START = 0,
    OSDP_HUB_TCP_IND,
    OSDP_HUB_AUTH_0,
    OSDP_HUB_AUTH_1,
    OSDP_HUB_AUTH_2,
    OSDP_HUB_AUTH_3,
    OSDP_HUB_AUTH_4,
    OSDP_HUB_PING,
    OSDP_HUB_PONG,
    OSDP_HUB_GET_AUTH_1,
    OSDP_HUB_GET_AUTH_3,
} osdp_hub_e;

struct _osdp_hub_messages_t
{
    osdp_hub_e     hub_msg;
    bool           enable;
    uint8_t        max_tcp;
    uint8_t        ip_addr[16];
    bool           ipv4;
    uint32_t       port;
    bool           success;
    uint8_t        username[17];
    uint8_t        publickey[321];
    uint8_t        salt[65];
    uint8_t        cryptogram[65];
    osdp_header_t* header;
};
typedef struct _osdp_hub_messages_t osdp_hub_messages_t;


/// @brief Translate the data structure to a packet for transmission
/// @param buffer An input data buffer used to store the packet
/// @param len The length of the output packet
void osdp_hub_messages_encode( osdp_hub_messages_t* data, uint8_t* buffer, int32_t* len );

/// @brief Translate a received packet into a data structure
/// @param data A struct containing the decoded output parameters
/// @param buffer An input data buffer used to store the packet
/// @param len The length of the input packet
/// @return The number of decoded bytes
int32_t osdp_hub_messages_decode( osdp_hub_messages_t* data, uint8_t* buffer, int32_t len );


#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif

//
// end of file
//
```

Anymore information required and i will surely add it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not look like SIA OSDP.  (According to Sensurity's web site that is the OSDP they are referring to.)  Perhaps this is some other part of the mechanism?  The current SIA OSDP working group activity regarding OSDP over an IP network is around OSDP over TCP (using the existing "secure channel" mechanism) or OSDP over TLS.